# Can we add custom scope in UAAC

Tags: authentication, microservices

I am working on CF-UAA. I want to define my application specific custom scope e.g. user.reports. I want this scope to be included in the token.
The token then validated by a report microservice and it will serve only if the token contains the scope.

My questions are:

1. Can we define custom scope and add users to it?
2. If yes how? and if not what is the best way to achieve this kind of requirement

Answer (score 2):

With some trial and errors, I found following

1. The scope for the user is nothing but his group association
2. When one wants to add the scope, first create a group

`uaac group add custom.report`

3. Add member to this group

`uaac member add custom.report xyz@abc.com`

4. But if you are trying to get the token for the user with this value in the scope using Token Issuer,

`ti = CF::UAA::TokenIssuer.new("http://localhost:8080/uaa", "reportclient")
 token = ti.owner_password_credentials_grant({ :username => request[:username],
                                               :password => request[:password]})`

Then you must have the 'reportclient' with authorities - 'custom.report'.

You can add the authority to reportclient with following command

```
uaac client update reportclient --authorities "<existing authorities list separated by space> custom.report"
```

Only then the token received will have custom.report scope.

Hope this helps someone.
And a better way if someone knows, is welcome.